# Compute the homology of the CW complex directly from the cell structure

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a CW-complex. Define an equivalence class on $X$ to be $\alpha(X)$, and $Y \in \alpha(X) \iff Y$ homotopy equivalent to $X$.

Define an ordering on cell structures:

1. The cell structure with a smaller number of cells is smaller. E.g. $e_0 \cup e_5 < e_0 \cup e_1 \cup e_2$ since $2 < 3$.
2. Given two cell structures with the *same number of cells*, the first dimension counting from $0$ in which the number of cells differs determines the smaller cell structure to be the one that has more cells in that dimension. E.g. $e_0 \cup e_3 < e_0 \cup e_4$ since the first dimension in which the cell multiplicities differ is $3$ and $e_0 \cup e_3$ has $1$ cell $e_3$ in that dimension while $e_0 \cup e_4$ has $0$ and $1 > 0$.

Define a *minimal cell structure* for $X$ to be the least cell structure out of all possible cell structures for all $Y \in \alpha(X)$ under the just defined ordering.

**Claim: For every dimension $n$, the betti number of $n$-th homology group of $X$ is the Cartesian power coefficient of the cell $e_n$ in the minimal cell structure of $X$.**

Examples:

1. $S^n = e_0 \cup e_n$, $H_i(S^n)=\mathbb{Z}$ if $\in \{0, n\}$, $H_i(S^n)=\mathbb{0}$ if $i \notin \{0, n\}$, claim holds here, $S^n$ is orientable.
2. $T^2 = e_0 \cup e_1^2 \cup e_2$, $H_0(T^2) = \mathbb{Z}$, $H_1(T^2) = \mathbb{Z}^2$, $H_2(T^2) = \mathbb{Z}$, $H_i(T^2) = 0$ for $i>2$, claim holds, $T^2$ is orientable.
3. Solid Torus. $D^2 \times S^1 = e_0 \cup e_1^2 \cup e_2^2 \cup e_3$, but $D^2 \times S^1$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 = e_0 \cup e_1$ which has fewer cells in its cell structure. Hence $H_i(D^2 \times S^1) = \mathbb{Z} \iff i \in \{0,1\}$ and $H_i(D^2 \times S^1) = \mathbb{0} \iff i > 1$, claim holds, the solid torus is orientable and all its homology groups are torsion-free.
4. Projective space $\mathbb{R}P^2=e_0 \cup e_1 \cup e_2$ and $H_0(\mathbb{R}P^2)=\mathbb{Z}$, $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)=\mathbb{Z_2}$, $H_i(\mathbb{R}P^2)=0, i>1$. But $\mathbb{R}P^2$. The claim does not hold. $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is not orientable.
5. Projective space $\mathbb{R}P^3=e_0 \cup e_1 \cup e_2 \cup e_3$ and $H_0(\mathbb{R}P^3)=\mathbb{Z}$, $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^3)=\mathbb{Z_2}$, $H_3(\mathbb{R}P^3)=\mathbb{Z}$, $H_i(\mathbb{R}P^3)=0, i>3$ or $i=2$. The claim does not hold. $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is not orientable. It has $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^3)=\mathbb{Z_2}$ which is not torsion-free.

Question: **What are the least restricting conditions for a $CW$-complex implying the claim?** It may hard to find the most general conditions, but the more general the more I will appreciate the answer!

Some of the conditions on $X$ to consider:

1. $X$ is orientable.
2. homology groups of $X$ are torsion-free.
3. $X$ is a manifold.

Comment: What is an "orientable CW complex"? ($\mathbb{R}P^1$ is an orientable manifold, by the way, since it's just a circle. Maybe you're thinking about $\mathbb{R}P^2$.) What about $\mathbb{R}P^3$?

Comment: What if there isn't a unique minimal cell structure?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I added an additional alphabetical ordering on the cell structures.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thank you for your observation, I edited the question.

Comment: Generally when one writes "Claim:..." it means something that is later shown to be true.  It seems a little weird to claim something you know is false.  Also, "Under what conditions does statement X hold?" is, notoriously, a rather lazy question.  The obvious necessary and sufficient condition for X is...X!  If you want to get more than that as an answer, you should put more into motivating the question: here, why should we consider your rather strange-looking criterion?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I thought that the many nice examples for which the claim holds is the sufficient motivation for finding the sufficient condition for the claim to hold. I also thought that something similar is already discovered and some insightful mathematician would just answer with some already known theorem - but this does not seem to be the case. I do not think the question is lazy - it rather asks for much. I myself would like to find the condition implying the claim but currently I do not even know from where to start. I will have to learn much more to be able to find something meaningful!

Comment: @David: Questions which are easy to ask but hard to answer are in a sense "lazy".  They could also be important/profound, but the burden is on the asker to show that this is the case.  You can see what Kevin Buzzard wrote about this here: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/73/questions-that-arent-maths-questions/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a CW-complex whose cellular chain complex $C_{\bullet}(X)$ has all zero differentials.  Note that this necessarily occurs when $X$ does not have cells in consecutive dimensions, e.g. $S^n$ for $n \geq 2$, $\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}^n$ for $n \geq 1$.  It also occurs for $S^1$.  Then $C_n(X) \cong H_n(X,\mathbb{Z})$ for all $n$.  Such a complex must be "minimal" in your sense: if you had fewer cells in any given dimension that would give rise to a smaller Betti number.

It follows from the Eilenberg-Zilber Theorem that a finite product of CW-complexes with all zero differentials has all zero differentials.  This shows for instance that the $n$-dimensional torus has this property for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.  In particular this explains all of your examples.

Conversely, let $X$ be a finite CW-complex whose $n$th Betti number is equal to the number of $n$-cells for all $n$.  Let $d_n$ be the $n$th differential in the singular complex.
Let $K_n$ be the kernel of $d_n$ and $I_{n}$ be the image of $d_{n+1}$.  Then 
$K_n \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$, so $K_n \cong \mathbb{Z}^d$ for some $d \leq n$.  Further $K_n/I_n \cong \mathbb{Z}^n \oplus T$ for a finite abelian group $T$, so $\mathbb{Z}^n \oplus T$ is a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}^d$.  We must then have $d =n$ and $T = 0$, so the map $K_n \rightarrow K_n/I_n$ is a surjective map from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to itself.  Such a thing is known to be an isomorphism, e.g. by structure theory of finitely generated modules over a PID.  In other words $I_n = 0$ and all the differentials are trivial.  In particular all of the homology groups are free abelian.

Comment: For reference a similar topic of the question is covered in Hatcher, 4.C Minimal Cell Structures.